# How can I move this object with the arrow keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I made an object out of a div in html and CSS to make a player for my game I am making and I can't get the player to move when I press the arrow keys. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Here is the Javascript:

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");    
var velocity = 5;    
let player = {    
  height:20,    
  width:20,    
  x:200,    
  y:200    
}    
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){    
if(event.keyCode === 37){    
    player.x -= velocity:           
else if(event.keyCode ===38){    
    player.y -=velocity;    
}    
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_controllers_keys

Comment: No you are wrong you are only modifying the variable and that doesn't have any change on player

Comment: Answered.Take a look

Answer (score 1):

Moving a div using simple `Javascript` just adding switch on keydown event on document and then customzing the css of div (player) top-left

```js
var player = $('#player');
var velocity = 5;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
      player.css('left', player.offset().left - velocity);
      break;
    case 38:
      player.css('top', player.offset().top - velocity);
      break;
    case 39:
      player.css('left', player.offset().left + velocity);
      break;
    case 40:
      player.css('top', player.offset().top + velocity);
      break;
  }
})
```

```css
#player {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the element or player showed up on the canvas but it still will not move.

Comment: There is no canvas in it.

Comment: then why when i put that exact code it still will not move?

Comment: Just keep in mind that the document has focused. then press the buttons to move the player . please check the snippet

Answer (score 0):

With an addition to Ibnelaiq's answer, here's a way to make sure the players can move better -

```js
var key = [];
function keys(db, e) {
  var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (db == false && key.includes(code) === false) {
    key.push(code);
  } else if (db === true) {
    key.splice(key.indexOf(code));
  }
}
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(key);
}, 30);
document.getElementsByClassName('game')[0].getContext('2d').fillText('Click here and press keys', 10, 10);
```

```css
.game {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas class='game' tabindex='1' width='400px' height='290px' onkeydown='keys(false, event)' onkeyup='keys(true, event)'>
```

What this does:

`<canvas>` (not limited to `<canvas>` though) waits for `keydown` and adds `event.keycode` or `event.which` to the array. It also waits for `keyup`, and removes whatever `event.keycode` or `event.which` was released from the array.

The `setInterval` is just there to log the array into the console. The last line in the code is there to write text into `<canvas>`.

Of course, you can add his `switch` statement into the `setInterval`, but in there only.